# Angular Route Rule Not Working As Expected

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the `matcher` property of `Route` to define routing rules for my app, instead of the usual `path` property. This is the first time i am doing this, and docs on this feature is pretty scarce. However, I found little info on usage at [UrlMatcher](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher).

Here is my trimmed route file:

```
const registeredResources = [
    'clusters',
    'users',
    'teams',
    'repositories',
    'records',
    'projects',
    'feeds',
    'feedback'
];

function registeredResourcesOnly(url: UrlSegment[], group: UrlSegmentGroup,         route: Route) {
    return (url.length > 0) && (registeredResources.includes(url[0].path)) ?     ({ consumed: [url[0]] }) : null;
    }

    export const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { 
        matcher: registeredResourcesOnly,
        canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
        loadChildren: '../sb/resource/resource.module#ResourceModule',
    }
];
```

It works fine on every first request (http://localhost:4200/clusters or http://localhost:4200/users etc), but doesn't on every second request (ResourceModule does not get loaded the second time).

It works fine with `path`, so I think it might have something to do with combining `matcher` and `loadChildren`.

Comment: _ResourceModule does not get loaded the second time_ - what do you mean? It loads it one time and caches . can you setup a plunker?

Comment: by "loaded", i mean it does not get activated on any subsequent url request after the first.

Comment: what do you mean `activated`?

Comment: @Maximus i would do a plunker of the issue and get back to you